# ES6 Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: express, ecmascript-6

Now I worked with Node.js + Express to make some api server.

I installed `babel-preset-latest` to use ES6 statement.

However, When I write some code, it throws error ->

`Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`

[index.js]

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('main');
});
app.use('/api', require('./api/auth'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Express Running port 3000")
})
```

[/api/auth/index.js]

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', (res, req) => {
    res.send('auth main')
});

export default router;
```

In ES6, `module.export` can replace to `export`.

But it throw errors. So, after I replace `export default router;` to `module.exports = router;`, It works perfectly.

Why do I get this error? Is there any syntax error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

[index.js]

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import authRouter from './api/auth';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('main');
});
app.use('/api', authRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Express Running port 3000")
})
```

[/api/auth/index.js]

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', (res, req) => {
    res.send('auth main')
});

export default router;
```

in index.js, Define import statement -> `import authRouter from './api/auth';`

and replace `app.use('/api', require('./api/auth');`

to

`app.use('/api', authRouter);`

Comment: You made my day, after a couple hrs of struggle!

Comment: @gildniy Good job :)